# Adapt observable to D3 but nothing rendering in the web page

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am following the tutorial in https://observablehq.com/@d3/bar-chart-race-explained.

I am using chrome with version 89.0.4389.90 to test the code.

I mostly copied the code and downloaded the data csv file, and I am trying to run the code locally - here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Assignment1</title>

    <script src="d3.v6.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!--<svg width="1600" height="800" id="mainsvg" class="svgs"></svg>-->
    <script>
      let margin = { top: 16, right: 6, bottom: 6, left: 0 };
      let barSize = 48;
      let n = 12;
      let width = 1600;
      let duration = 250;
      let height = margin.top + barSize * n + margin.bottom;

      d3.csv("category-brands.csv").then((data) => {
        const x = d3.scaleLinear([0, 1], [margin.left, width - margin.right]);
        const y = d3
          .scaleBand()
          .domain(d3.range(n + 1))
          .rangeRound([margin.top, margin.top + barSize * (n + 1 + 0.1)])
          .padding(0.1);

        const names = new Set(data.map((d) => d.name));
        console.log(names);

        let datevalues = Array.from(
          d3.rollup(
            data,
            ([d]) => +d.value,
            (d) => d.date,
            (d) => d.name
          )
        );
        console.log(datevalues);
        datevalues = datevalues
          .map(([date, data]) => [new Date(date), data])
          .sort(([a], [b]) => d3.ascending(a, b));

        console.log("datavalues:", datevalues);

        function rank(value) {
          const data = Array.from(names, (name) => ({
            name,
            value: value(name),
          }));
          data.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value));
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) data[i].rank = Math.min(n, i);
          return data;
        }
        console.log(
          "rank",
          rank((name) => datevalues[0][1].get(name))
        );

        const k = 10;

        const keyframes = (function () {
          const keyframes = [];
          let ka, a, kb, b;
          for ([[ka, a], [kb, b]] of d3.pairs(datevalues)) {
            for (let i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
              const t = i / k;
              keyframes.push([
                new Date(ka * (1 - t) + kb * t),
                rank(
                  (name) =>
                    (a.get(name) || 0) * (1 - t) + (b.get(name) || 0) * t
                ),
              ]);
            }
          }
          keyframes.push([new Date(kb), rank((name) => b.get(name) || 0)]);
          return keyframes;
        })();

        console.log("total frames:", keyframes.length);
        console.log("total frames:", keyframes);

        let nameframes = d3.groups(
          keyframes.flatMap(([, data]) => data),
          (d) => d.name
        );
        console.log("name frames number:", nameframes.length);
        console.log("name frames:", nameframes);

        let prev = new Map(
          nameframes.flatMap(([, data]) => d3.pairs(data, (a, b) => [b, a]))
        );
        let next = new Map(nameframes.flatMap(([, data]) => d3.pairs(data)));

        console.log("pref:", prev);
        console.log("next:", next);
        function bars(svg) {
          let bar = svg.append("g").attr("fill-opacity", 0.6).selectAll("rect");

          return ([date, data], transition) =>
            (bar = bar
              .data(data.slice(0, n), (d) => d.name)
              .join(
                (enter) =>
                  enter
                    .append("rect")
                    .attr("fill", color)
                    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
                    .attr("x", x(0))
                    .attr("y", (d) => y((prev.get(d) || d).rank))
                    .attr("width", (d) => x((prev.get(d) || d).value) - x(0)),
                (update) => update,
                (exit) =>
                  exit
                    .transition(transition)
                    .remove()
                    .attr("y", (d) => y((next.get(d) || d).rank))
                    .attr("width", (d) => x((next.get(d) || d).value) - x(0))
              )
              .call((bar) =>
                bar
                  .transition(transition)
                  .attr("y", (d) => y(d.rank))
                  .attr("width", (d) => x(d.value) - x(0))
              ));
        }

        function labels(svg) {
          let label = svg
            .append("g")
            .style("font", "bold 12px var(--sans-serif)")
            .style("font-variant-numeric", "tabular-nums")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .selectAll("text");

          return ([date, data], transition) =>
            (label = label
              .data(data.slice(0, n), (d) => d.name)
              .join(
                (enter) =>
                  enter
                    .append("text")
                    .attr(
                      "transform",
                      (d) =>
                        `translate(${x((prev.get(d) || d).value)},${y(
                          (prev.get(d) || d).rank
                        )})`
                    )
                    .attr("y", y.bandwidth() / 2)
                    .attr("x", -6)
                    .attr("dy", "-0.25em")
                    .text((d) => d.name)
                    .call((text) =>
                      text
                        .append("tspan")
                        .attr("fill-opacity", 0.7)
                        .attr("font-weight", "normal")
                        .attr("x", -6)
                        .attr("dy", "1.15em")
                    ),
                (update) => update,
                (exit) =>
                  exit
                    .transition(transition)
                    .remove()
                    .attr(
                      "transform",
                      (d) =>
                        `translate(${x((next.get(d) || d).value)},${y(
                          (next.get(d) || d).rank
                        )})`
                    )
                    .call((g) =>
                      g
                        .select("tspan")
                        .tween("text", (d) =>
                          textTween(d.value, (next.get(d) || d).value)
                        )
                    )
              )
              .call((bar) =>
                bar
                  .transition(transition)
                  .attr(
                    "transform",
                    (d) => `translate(${x(d.value)},${y(d.rank)})`
                  )
                  .call((g) =>
                    g
                      .select("tspan")
                      .tween("text", (d) =>
                        textTween((prev.get(d) || d).value, d.value)
                      )
                  )
              ));
        }

        function textTween(a, b) {
          const i = d3.interpolateNumber(a, b);
          return function (t) {
            this.textContent = formatNumber(i(t));
          };
        }

        formatNumber = d3.format(",d");

        function axis(svg) {
          const g = svg
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform", `translate(0,${margin.top})`);

          const axis = d3
            .axisTop(x)
            .ticks(width / 160)
            .tickSizeOuter(0)
            .tickSizeInner(-barSize * (n + y.padding()));

          return (_, transition) => {
            g.transition(transition).call(axis);
            g.select(".tick:first-of-type text").remove();
            g.selectAll(".tick:not(:first-of-type) line").attr(
              "stroke",
              "white"
            );
            g.select(".domain").remove();
          };
        }

        function ticker(svg) {
          const now = svg
            .append("text")
            .style("font", `bold ${barSize}px var(--sans-serif)`)
            .style("font-variant-numeric", "tabular-nums")
            .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("x", width - 6)
            .attr("y", margin.top + barSize * (n - 0.45))
            .attr("dy", "0.32em")
            .text(formatDate(keyframes[0][0]));

          return ([date], transition) => {
            transition.end().then(() => now.text(formatDate(date)));
          };
        }

        let formatDate = d3.utcFormat("%Y");

        let color = (function () {
          const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeTableau10);
          if (data.some((d) => d.category !== undefined)) {
            const categoryByName = new Map(
              data.map((d) => [d.name, d.category])
            );
            scale.domain(categoryByName.values());
            return (d) => scale(categoryByName.get(d.name));
          }
          return (d) => scale(d.name);
        })();

        const svg = d3.create("svg").attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height]);
        const updateBars = bars(svg);
        const updateAxis = axis(svg);
        const updateLabels = labels(svg);
        const updateTicker = ticker(svg);

        const start = async function () {
          for (const keyframe of keyframes) {
            const transition = svg
              .transition()
              .duration(duration)
              .ease(d3.easeLinear);

            console.log("iteration..");
            // Extract the top bar’s value.
            x.domain([0, keyframe[1][0].value]);

            updateAxis(keyframe, transition);
            updateBars(keyframe, transition);
            updateLabels(keyframe, transition);
            updateTicker(keyframe, transition);

            await transition.end();
          }
        };
        start();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have altered the code to run without observablehq's environment, but, after running the code, nothing was showing on the web page.

The console log shows that the data processing logic is normal, but for the rending part, it does nothing except printing `iteration`.

What is the problem with my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach the `svg` you just created to some element in the HTML to see the output.

`d3.create` just creates a detached element. Since you are not attaching it anywhere, we are not seeing the output in the screen.

We can use `d3.select` to select where we want to place this chart and use then `.append`.

`d3.select('#chart').append('svg')`

```js
const fileUrl =
  'https://static.observableusercontent.com/files/aec3792837253d4c6168f9bbecdf495140a5f9bb1cdb12c7c8113cec26332634a71ad29b446a1e8236e0a45732ea5d0b4e86d9d1568ff5791412f093ec06f4f1?response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename*%3DUTF-8%27%27category-brands.csv';

let margin = {
  top: 16,
  right: 6,
  bottom: 6,
  left: 0,
};
let barSize = 48;
let n = 12;
let width = 1600;
let duration = 250;
let height = margin.top + barSize * n + margin.bottom;

d3.csv(fileUrl).then((data) => {
  const x = d3.scaleLinear([0, 1], [margin.left, width - margin.right]);
  const y = d3
    .scaleBand()
    .domain(d3.range(n + 1))
    .rangeRound([margin.top, margin.top + barSize * (n + 1 + 0.1)])
    .padding(0.1);

  const names = new Set(data.map((d) => d.name));

  let datevalues = Array.from(
    d3.rollup(
      data,
      ([d]) => +d.value,
      (d) => d.date,
      (d) => d.name
    )
  );

  datevalues = datevalues
    .map(([date, data]) => [new Date(date), data])
    .sort(([a], [b]) => d3.ascending(a, b));

  function rank(value) {
    const data = Array.from(names, (name) => ({
      name,
      value: value(name),
    }));
    data.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a.value, b.value));
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) data[i].rank = Math.min(n, i);
    return data;
  }

  const k = 10;

  const keyframes = (function () {
    const keyframes = [];
    let ka, a, kb, b;
    for ([[ka, a], [kb, b]] of d3.pairs(datevalues)) {
      for (let i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        const t = i / k;
        keyframes.push([
          new Date(ka * (1 - t) + kb * t),
          rank((name) => (a.get(name) || 0) * (1 - t) + (b.get(name) || 0) * t),
        ]);
      }
    }
    keyframes.push([new Date(kb), rank((name) => b.get(name) || 0)]);
    return keyframes;
  })();

  console.log('total frames:', keyframes.length);
  console.log('total frames:', keyframes);

  let nameframes = d3.groups(
    keyframes.flatMap(([, data]) => data),
    (d) => d.name
  );

  console.log('name frames number:', nameframes.length);
  console.log('name frames:', nameframes);

  let prev = new Map(
    nameframes.flatMap(([, data]) => d3.pairs(data, (a, b) => [b, a]))
  );
  let next = new Map(nameframes.flatMap(([, data]) => d3.pairs(data)));

  console.log('pref:', prev);
  console.log('next:', next);

  function bars(svg) {
    let bar = svg.append('g').attr('fill-opacity', 0.6).selectAll('rect');

    return ([date, data], transition) =>
      (bar = bar
        .data(data.slice(0, n), (d) => d.name)
        .join(
          (enter) =>
            enter
              .append('rect')
              .attr('fill', color)
              .attr('height', y.bandwidth())
              .attr('x', x(0))
              .attr('y', (d) => y((prev.get(d) || d).rank))
              .attr('width', (d) => x((prev.get(d) || d).value) - x(0)),
          (update) => update,
          (exit) =>
            exit
              .transition(transition)
              .remove()
              .attr('y', (d) => y((next.get(d) || d).rank))
              .attr('width', (d) => x((next.get(d) || d).value) - x(0))
        )
        .call((bar) =>
          bar
            .transition(transition)
            .attr('y', (d) => y(d.rank))
            .attr('width', (d) => x(d.value) - x(0))
        ));
  }

  function labels(svg) {
    let label = svg
      .append('g')
      .style('font', 'bold 12px var(--sans-serif)')
      .style('font-variant-numeric', 'tabular-nums')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
      .selectAll('text');

    return ([date, data], transition) =>
      (label = label
        .data(data.slice(0, n), (d) => d.name)
        .join(
          (enter) =>
            enter
              .append('text')
              .attr(
                'transform',
                (d) =>
                  `translate(${x((prev.get(d) || d).value)},${y(
                    (prev.get(d) || d).rank
                  )})`
              )
              .attr('y', y.bandwidth() / 2)
              .attr('x', -6)
              .attr('dy', '-0.25em')
              .text((d) => d.name)
              .call((text) =>
                text
                  .append('tspan')
                  .attr('fill-opacity', 0.7)
                  .attr('font-weight', 'normal')
                  .attr('x', -6)
                  .attr('dy', '1.15em')
              ),
          (update) => update,
          (exit) =>
            exit
              .transition(transition)
              .remove()
              .attr(
                'transform',
                (d) =>
                  `translate(${x((next.get(d) || d).value)},${y(
                    (next.get(d) || d).rank
                  )})`
              )
              .call((g) =>
                g
                  .select('tspan')
                  .tween('text', (d) =>
                    textTween(d.value, (next.get(d) || d).value)
                  )
              )
        )
        .call((bar) =>
          bar
            .transition(transition)
            .attr('transform', (d) => `translate(${x(d.value)},${y(d.rank)})`)
            .call((g) =>
              g
                .select('tspan')
                .tween('text', (d) =>
                  textTween((prev.get(d) || d).value, d.value)
                )
            )
        ));
  }

  function textTween(a, b) {
    const i = d3.interpolateNumber(a, b);
    return function (t) {
      this.textContent = formatNumber(i(t));
    };
  }

  formatNumber = d3.format(',d');

  function axis(svg) {
    const g = svg.append('g').attr('transform', `translate(0,${margin.top})`);

    const axis = d3
      .axisTop(x)
      .ticks(width / 160)
      .tickSizeOuter(0)
      .tickSizeInner(-barSize * (n + y.padding()));

    return (_, transition) => {
      g.transition(transition).call(axis);
      g.select('.tick:first-of-type text').remove();
      g.selectAll('.tick:not(:first-of-type) line').attr('stroke', 'white');
      g.select('.domain').remove();
    };
  }

  function ticker(svg) {
    const now = svg
      .append('text')
      .style('font', `bold ${barSize}px var(--sans-serif)`)
      .style('font-variant-numeric', 'tabular-nums')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'end')
      .attr('x', width - 6)
      .attr('y', margin.top + barSize * (n - 0.45))
      .attr('dy', '0.32em')
      .text(formatDate(keyframes[0][0]));

    return ([date], transition) => {
      transition.end().then(() => now.text(formatDate(date)));
    };
  }

  let formatDate = d3.utcFormat('%Y');

  let color = (function () {
    const scale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeTableau10);
    if (data.some((d) => d.category !== undefined)) {
      const categoryByName = new Map(data.map((d) => [d.name, d.category]));
      scale.domain(categoryByName.values());
      return (d) => scale(categoryByName.get(d.name));
    }
    return (d) => scale(d.name);
  })();

  const svg = d3.select('#chart').append('svg').attr('viewBox', [0, 0, width, height]);
  const updateBars = bars(svg);
  const updateAxis = axis(svg);
  const updateLabels = labels(svg);
  const updateTicker = ticker(svg);

  const start = async function () {
    for (const keyframe of keyframes) {
      const transition = svg
        .transition()
        .duration(duration)
        .ease(d3.easeLinear);

      // Extract the top bar’s value.
      x.domain([0, keyframe[1][0].value]);

      updateAxis(keyframe, transition);
      updateBars(keyframe, transition);
      updateLabels(keyframe, transition);
      updateTicker(keyframe, transition);

      await transition.end();
    }
  };
  start();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Dude thanks, maybe I am just stupid but the way the original author is showing us the code for the Bar Chart Race is super confusing.

Comment: @RodrigoAlvarez I would recommend reading the tutorial linked by the author (OP), which explains in detail. Do not be overwhelmed by seeing the code, you can slowly read the tutorial to understand.